# sculpt mode STILL glitchy

Tags: edit-mode, faces, sculpting

using blender 2.79
When i use sculpt tools like inflates/deflate some faces inflate like they should, and HALF of them just so wherever they want...

I've been having troubles for months, and been ALL OVER google and back, tried absolutely everything, and I STILL can't figure out why my sculpt mode keeps going in random directions.

The normal are in the right directions, there are NO modifiers on my mesh, I've tried deleting and replacing the faces, re-sizing, checked all my settings, and STILL nothing.

Maybe I'm missing something as I'm fairly new to blender and mostly self taught, and I'm not sure how much more I can describe this problem as I seem to be the only person having this problem, but I'm happy to answer to any request of further details.

[image]

Comment: Are the normals all correct?

Comment: yes, as i stated above, i've done everything i can

Comment: Could you show some screen shots that include the brush settings as well? Sometimes the simplest answer is a setting that is accidentally made...

Comment: I think i got all of them, not sure witch settings you mean so i got as many as i could, let me know if you need anything else, i've also learned that it's only for this ONE specific mesh (all the separate parts sculpts fine)
 https://i.imgur.com/2adKqnP.png

Comment: Try applying scale in Object mode (Ctrl+A > Scale), then check if there any problems with mesh geometry. Normally this can happen if either normals are inconsistent (which you stated isn't the case) or if vertices are already moved so much that form distorted surface. Also mesh is quite lowpoly so I don't see what really to sculpt there. If you want someone to check your file upload it here https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: i said i've alreays tried scaling and it didn't work (i've tried all the solutions multiple times to see if i did it wrong the first time) sadly no success. and this head is very much unfinished o that's why it looks like crap (i just prefer to use sculpt tools even on small meshes with even lower poly) I'm not sure what else to do, i think i'm to shy to share my file, I just started over and remade the entire head so problem 'solved'?
thank you for trying to help though

Comment: wait you said OBJECT mode? there's my problem i was trying in edit mode, sorry i'm a little slow, again thank you for helping (i already remade the head) but if i have this problem again i know several ways to fix it.
Thanks bud